# OSM data convert to old microstation dgn format

Tags: microstation, dgn

I'd like to convert OSM data into dgn file (version J), with my projection. I'd like you it as a reference file. Is this possible?

I try to save it in QGIS. Is this solve with Microstation V8 version program?

When I open it in Microstation J, the dgn content show on the zero coordinates.

What is my mistake?

In QGIS, I save file in Microstation DGN, after that I open it Microstation J but the projection is not good.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add more steps (with screenshots) this should be possible.

Comment: I uploaded two pictures about it.

Comment: I solve my problem. I download data from geofabrik, after that I change projectionto my country proj. Then I use FME workbench trial. In that I check all v9 only parameter and off it. It works fine. :)